# Any library to convert richtext to html

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

At present I am using [widgEditor](http://code.google.com/p/widgeditor/)

It is a good library in JavaScript but has some minor issues. Is there any other library that can convert a Rich Text into an HTML equivalent?

Comment: widgEditor is not converting rich text to html but its a rich text editor in JavaScript. You can google "wysiwyg editor" you will get plenty of them ..

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=wysiwyg+editor+javascript&aq=0&oq=wysiwyg+editor+java&aqi=g1g-m2

Comment: You can use CSS.  Rich text is only a presentation convention for raw text and HTML is not a presentation language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better library. Just want to share for other members.

http://www.openwebware.com/

It is working fine for me and is simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a WYSISYG editor you're after; I've been using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for a while. It's packed with features but still very speedy. I recommend you to check it out.

Most information you need regarding setting it up is found on their [Developer's Guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide). However, you basically just need to extract it to the root (configurable) of your website, include the `ckeditor.js` file inside your `head` element and then "replace" your regular `textarea` element using the `replace()` function, preferably just after the DOM has been loaded, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace("textarea1");
};
```

Comment: I saw samples but still it is not working. Can you please illustrate how to use it with TextArea?